# Will my HDD's get checked when leaving the country at UK airport?

Tags: airport-security

About one year ago i came to the UK with my computer split into its components, each of them in their particular box that it was delivered with, and my two internal HDD's in a separate gpu box, all of them in the hand luggage. I couldn't take the computer case with me, which is why i only took the components.

Now i have to return to my country (in the euro zone) and would like to do the same thing, but i was wondering if the contents of my internal HDD's are going to get checked at the airport?

Comment: I have to ask: what exactly do you have on those HDDs?

Comment: i have mostly work stuff and...a few pictures of me and my wife that i wouldn't want other people to see, you know...

Comment: I have travelled with HDDs more than once and to different destinations, I have never had them inspected not even once, I always wondered if it ever happened to anybody

Comment: Upload the pictures to your favorite Cloud storage (Dropbox, Google Drive) and delete them from your laptop.  Hypothetical problem solved.

Comment: Thank you!! I've never used cloud storage before, but i imagine it can't be that hard haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While theoretically possible, that would be **exceedingly unlikely**, as there are no Customs inspections for departing passengers, even for flights outside the EU.  And since if you're staying within the EU, you're also staying within the [EUCU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_Customs_Union) and there are no Customs controls at all.

That said, if you happen to be on (say) an Interpol watch list for child pornography and are flagged on buying the ticket or checking in, you may well be stopped and searched by regular police.

Comment: .. or someone else with your name is on a list of suspects (more likely)